# How to get apk directly from market

Tags: android, google-play

I m new to android , i want to know how to get the apk file directly from the android market and save it in my desktop to make use of it later in offline, any ideas are welcome

Comment: As I know, you can't download an APK file on a non-android device from Android Market.

Comment: No , we can download the apk. there are more ways to get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Astro applications from android market to back up all the applications as you need. You can

Comment: Wow! ooh!! yeah!!! , its working man, great answer, good job.

Answer (score 2):

That is intentionally not allowed to download apk file directly.

Comment: oh ok, i appreciate u for ur fast reply, brillinant guy

Comment: Your answer is correct for normal phones. But it seems that all the guys from India have rooted phones, which do not have all this restrictions.